# Disable wrapping in emacs isearch

Tags: search, emacs

How can I configure emacs not to allow wrapped isearch?

That is, if there are no subsequent matches, I want C-s to do nothing (rather than wrapping around to the beginning of the buffer), and if there are no previous matches, I want C-r to do nothing (rather than wrapping around to the end of the buffer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run the following with <kbd>M-:</kbd> if it works the way you want it to, save it to your `.emacs` -

```
(setq isearch-wrap-function '(lambda nil))
```

Comment: There seems to be a very small bug in that a C-s/C-r when the search is failing doesn't actually do nothing, it changes the status from "Failing I-search: foo" to "Failing wrapped I-search: foo", but that is entirely cosmetic.

Comment: Aye, that's because in `isearch.el` it is actually assuming it has wrapped the search. Maybe there is a cleaner way to do this, but I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
 (setq isearch-wrap-function '(lambda nil))
```

See http://www.nntpnews.info/threads/2950892-Preventing-wrap-searches